# Counting book inventory by user

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hadoop

There is a table which contains data from 2014.The structure is as follows:
Each user can issue different number of book category.

```
User-id|Book-Category
1      |Thrill        
2      |Thrill       
3      |Mystery       
3      |Mystery
```

The requirement is to find for each user,each type of book category issued.This data is already there in csv files but it is year wise available.
I have to add all those values.
eg:

```
data for 2014
u-id|book|count
1   |b1  |2  
1   |b2  |4
...  ...  ...

data for 2015
u-id|book|count
1   |b1  |21
2   |b3  |12  
//like the above format,available till 2018.(user1 with book b1 should have a count of 23
```

Now,I wrote a python script in which I just made a dictionary and iterated each row,if the key(u-id+book-category) was present,added the values of **count** otherwise,inserted key-value pair in that dictionary,did this for every year wise file in that script,since some files have size>1.5GB,the script kept on running for 7/8 hours,had to stop it.

Code:

```
    import requests
    import csv
    import pandas as pd

    Dict = {}

    with open('data_2012.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['a']+row['b'] not in Dict:
                Dict[row['a']+row['b']] = row['c']
##like this,iterating over the year wise files and finally writing the data to a different file.'a' and 'b' are mentioned at the first line of the data files for an easy access.
```

Is there any way with which we can achieve this functionality more elegantly in python or write a Map-Reduce job?

Comment: Would be really useful if you could show your Python script... Maybe it takes so long because it's 1) single threaded and you should probably be using something like Pyspark? 2) Processing CSV or plaintext out of Hadoop is horribly inefficient? And please don't use plain mapreduce if you don't have to... For example , this could just as easily be done with Hive, and I could write python/pandas code to process a 1.5GB csv in less than a few minutes, so what is your code really doing??

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007,please excuse the delay,updated the question, please review and suggest if it could be made faster, thanks for your time.

Comment: You're importing Pandas, but not even using it. Start with that before trying mapreduce or Spark https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Don't `for` loop it. Try reading it into a dataframe, albeit filtered or in chunks, and let pandas perform the operation.